# darken background image (Opacity?)

Tags: tailwind-css

So, I am using tailwind and I am trying to darken the background image that loads for this header. The purpose of this is I want to make sure the text is readable regardless of what someone picks for a background image.

````
<div :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${profile.cover_photo_path})` }" class="bg-center bg-cover h-48 w-full grid grid-cols-9 text-white shadow-2xl rounded-xl p-2">
            <div class="col-span-2 mx-auto my-auto">
                <img :src="profile.profile_photo_path" class="rounded-full h-36 w-36 border-4 border-red-700" />
            </div>
            <div class="pl-4 md:pl-0 col-span-2 grid content-center">
                <div class="text-lg font-logo uppercase">
                    {{profile.name}}
                </div>
                <div class="text-sm font-light">
                    {{profile.user_city}}, {{profile.user_region}}, {{profile.user_country}}
                </div>
                <div class="text-sm font-light">
                    {{calculateAge}} years old
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-span-3 grid content-end">
                
            </div>
            <div class="text-lg uppercase col-span-1 grid content-end justify-end">
                <div class="mx-auto">
                    <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm leading-4 font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-red-700 hover:bg-red-800 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-red-600">
                        <PlusIcon class="-ml-0.5 mr-2 h-4 w-4" aria-hidden="true" />
                        Follow
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-lg uppercase col-span-1 grid content-end justify-center">
                <div class="mx-auto">
                    <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm leading-4 font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-red-700 hover:bg-red-800 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-red-600">
                        <MailIcon class="-ml-0.5 mr-2 h-4 w-4" aria-hidden="true" />
                        Message
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    ```

I am open to other ideas but in my head it would be an opacity that would fix this. If you have another idea that would be more effective for this header/cover please let me know.
````

Comment: Specify the question with the screenshot of actual results you want

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to take an absolute image and control it as you want.

Like this: [Tailwind Play Link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/08UjIqv1AV)

Answer (score 0):

I had masked a `div` of the same dimensions but of black color behind your header and made the opacity of the header to `0.7`.

I had added div by this

```
<div class="h-48 w-full bg-black absolute"></div>
```

And added class `absolute z-10 opacity-70` to put the `header div` in front of `black div`.

> Also instead of using `:style="{ backgroundImage: url(path-name) }"` you can use `bg-[url(path-name)]` like I had used.

You can see the complete code here

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="absolute z-10 grid h-48 w-full grid-cols-9 rounded-xl bg-[url(http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back05.jpg)] bg-cover bg-center p-2 text-white opacity-60 shadow-2xl">
  <div class="col-span-2 mx-auto my-auto">
    <img src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/pang/IHXoEES.png" class="h-36 w-36 rounded-full border-4 border-pink-200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-span-2 grid content-center pl-4 md:pl-0">
    <div class="font-logo text-lg uppercase">{{profile.name}}</div>
    <div class="text-sm font-light">{{profile.user_city}}, {{profile.user_region}}, {{profile.user_country}}</div>
    <div class="text-sm font-light">{{calculateAge}} years old</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-span-3 grid content-end"></div>
  <div class="col-span-1 grid content-end justify-end text-lg uppercase">
    <div class="mx-auto">
      <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-red-700 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium leading-4 text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-red-800 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-red-600 focus:ring-offset-2">
        <PlusIcon class="-ml-0.5 mr-2 h-4 w-4" aria-hidden="true" />
        Follow
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-span-1 grid content-end justify-center text-lg uppercase">
    <div class="mx-auto">
      <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-red-700 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium leading-4 text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-red-800 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-red-600 focus:ring-offset-2">
        <MailIcon class="-ml-0.5 mr-2 h-4 w-4" aria-hidden="true" />
        Message
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="absolute h-48 w-full bg-black"></div>
```

> Ignore the warning and see in full view

Comment: Unfortunately the absolute impacts the whole design and the darken on the BG impacts all the children

Comment: So where you want to darken?